# How to show or print particular part from received byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi3

I am reading rpm from rpm sensing card through ttyS0 port of my pi3..

By sending "*01T%" to rpm card and rpm card response with "01X-000.0%".

And I want to show only 000.0 on my GUI window..

Please help me with my code..

```
import serial
import time
import threading
import queue
import tkinter as tk

class SerialThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
    def run(self):
        s = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyS0',baudrate=9600)
        string='*00T%'
        while True:
            s.write(str.encode('*00T%'))
            time.sleep(2)
            if s.inWaiting():
               text= s.readline(s.inWaiting())
               print(text)
               self.queue.put(text)
                #time.sleep(2)

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("640x640")
        frameLabel = tk.Frame(self, padx=40, pady =40)
        self.text = tk.Text(frameLabel, wrap='none', font='TimesNewRoman 37',
                            bg=self.cget('bg'), relief='flat')
        frameLabel.pack()
        self.text.pack()
        self.queue = queue.Queue()
        thread = SerialThread(self.queue)
        thread.start()
        self.process_serial()

    def process_serial(self):
          firstitem=True
          while self.queue.qsize():
            try:
                new=self.queue.get()
                if firstitem:
                 self.text.delete(1.0,'end')
                firstitem=False
                self.text.insert('end',new)
            except queue.Empty:
                pass
          self.after(100, self.process_serial)

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: if you know that the substring you are interested in is always between a `-` and `%` then its as simple as `text[text.index('-')+1:-1]`

Comment: @Nullman, i used this..what u r suggesting..but when i used this my Gui window showing nothing

Comment: @Nullman;;  this error coming while running this..as i am new to python,please help me to  ressolve this                                    text=temp[temp.index('-')+1:-1]
TypeError: argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'

Comment: what is `temp` here? it needs to be a string for this to work

Comment: temp is serially recieved 8bits data@Nullman,,bdw thanks for your idea ,i used <<temp=s.readline(s.inWaiting())
               value=temp.decode('utf-8')
               value=value[5:-1]
               print(value)>> and it works..but how can i do it with recieved bits...any suggestion..thanks in advance